# Getting Class of list with generic eg: List<Number>::class

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have a generically typed class `Builder<T>` that takes a constructor argument `Class<T>` so I can keep the type around. This is a class that I use a lot in java code so I don't want to change the signature.
When I try to use the constructor like this:

`Builder<List<Number>>(List<Number>::class)`

I get an error: "Only classes are allowed on the left hand side of a class literal"

Any way to resolve this?
I can't change the constructor for `Builder`, too many java classes rely upon it.

I understand the whole type erasure issue, I really just want to make the compiler happy.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Due to [generic type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html) `List` class has a single implementation for all its generic instantiations. You can only get a class corresponding to `List<*>` type, and thus create only `Builder<List<*>>`.

That builder instance is suitable for building a list of *something*. And again due to type erasure what that something is you can decide by yourself with the help of unchecked casts:

```
Builder(List::class.java) as Builder<List<Number>>
Builder(List::class.java as Class<List<Number>>)
```

Another approach is to create inline reified helper function:

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> Builder() = Builder(T::class.java)
```

and use it the following way:

```
Builder<List<Number>>()
```

Comment: reified is the way

Comment: This won't retain actual type parameters: `T::class.java` will represent `List<*>`, not `List<Number>`, but there's a solution that will do it for reified generics -- super class tokens.

Comment: @hotkey I assume `Builder` class doesn't require actual type parameters to be retained, because it takes a constructor argument `Class<T>` and not `Type` as it's stated in the question.

Comment: @Ilya what is the Builder class? Can you provide the package name?

Comment: @alexeypolusov it's the class from the question.

Answer (score 9):

The solution is to use [reified generics](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters) in couple with [super class tokens](http://gafter.blogspot.ru/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html).

Please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36253310/how-to-get-actual-type-arguments-of-a-reified-generic-parameter-in-kotlin) for the method explained. Constructors in Kotlin don't support reified generics, but you can use `TypeReference` described there to write a `builder` factory function which will retain actual generic parameters at runtime:

```
inline fun <reified T: Any> builder(): Builder<T> {
    val type = object : TypeReference<T>() {}.type
    return Builder(type)
}
```

Then inside `Builder` you can check if `type` is `ParameterizedType`, and if it is, `type.actualTypeArguments` will contain the actual generic parameters.

For example, `builder<List<Number>>()` will retain the information about `Number` at runtime.

The limitation of this approach is that you cannot use non-reified generic as a reified type parameter because the type must be known at compile-time.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use class of some instantiated list (code in Kotlin):

```
Builder(emptyList<Number>()::class.java)
```