# generics compilation error in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

There is a function. It is shown below.

```
fun <E, T : Collection<E>> constructCollectionType(collectionClass: Class<T>, elementClass: Class<E>): JavaType {
    return mapper.typeFactory.constructCollectionType(collectionClass, elementClass)
}
```

I call the function above in other function. The code is shown below.

```
val type = constructCollectionType<Sku, MutableList<Sku>>(MutableList<Sku>::class, Sku::class.java)
```

Then, kotlin compile give me an error.

`Only classes are allowed on the left hand side of a class literal.`

The only way I found is Reified type parameters. The code is shown below.

```
inline fun <reified E, reified T: Collection<E>> constructCollectionType():JavaType {
        return mapper.typeFactory.constructCollectionType(T::class.java, E::class.java)
}
```

Then, The call-site code is shown below.

```
jsonMapper.constructCollectionType<Sku, MutableList<Sku>>()
```

Is there any other solution ?

Comment: Are you asking this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37016058 ?

Comment: @JornVernee  thank you, the link you gave me supplies additional way, as seen below.
`val type = jsonMapper.constructCollectionType<Sku, MutableList<Sku>>((MutableList::class.java as Class<MutableList<Sku>>), Sku::class.java)`