# Can I create KType from reified T

Tags: generics, kotlin

I use reified generics to capture `KClass<>`

```
inline fun <reified T> register(generator: Generator<T>) {
    register(T::class, generator)
}
```

But `KType` has some additional properties which are interesting to me like nullability. I would like to write something like this to capture the `KType` instead.

```
inline fun <reified T> register(generator: Generator<T>) {
    register(T::ktype, generator) // Doesn't compile
}

...

register<String?>(myGen) // The nullability of String? is captured
```

Is there someway to capture `KType` instead of `KClass<>`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, as for now, this cannot be done, there is [an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-15992) in the Kotlin issue tracker about it, currently marked as *To be discussed*.

You can, however, get more than just `KClass<T>` from the reified type parameter using subclassing and, in particular, the [technique called super type tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36253310/how-to-get-actual-type-arguments-of-a-reified-generic-parameter-in-kotlin).

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of the super type tokens. This is something I will investigate. Looks like it can be good enough for my use case.

Comment: It looks like super type tokens only work in Kotlin/JVM and not in Kotlin/Common though?

Answer (score 4):

This is now possible in Kotlin 1.6 using the [`typeOf()` function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/type-of.html).

Comment: Thanks for the info