# Kotlin generic type issue

Tags: generics, kotlin

I'm lost in generic types many hours. I want to simplified the code but I can't cast object when its generic type. How I can solve this problem or another simplified way? `(I'm use kotlin 1.2)`

```
sealed class SETTING(override val key: String) : SettingsKeyContract

object optFirstLaunch : SETTING("first_launch"), SettingsKeyContractWithType<Boolean> {
    override val defaults = true
}

object optNotifications : SETTING("notification_list"), SettingsKeyContractWithType<List<String>> {
    override val defaults = emptyList<String>()
}

interface SettingsKeyContract { val key: String }
interface SettingsKeyContractWithType<T : Any> : SettingsKeyContract {

    val defaults: T

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    fun get(): T?       = (App.getContentComponent()?.getSettings()?.get(key)?.value?.data as? T)
    fun remove()        = (App.getContentComponent()?.getSettings())?.delete(key)
    fun save(value: T)  = (App.getContentComponent()?.getSettings()?.add(key, value))

}

class OptionModel(@OPTIONS_ID optionId: Int, contract: SettingsKeyContract)

val optionModel = OptionModel(1, optNotifications)
when(optionModel.contract){
    is SettingsKeyContractWithType<List<String>> -> (optionModel.contract as SettingsKeyContractWithType<List<String>>).set(listOf("ring-1", "ring-2")) //error
    is SettingsKeyContractWithType<Boolean> -> (optionModel.contract as SettingsKeyContractWithType<Boolean>).set(true)  //error
}
```

Error:

```
Cannot check for instance of erased type: SettingsKeyContractWithType<...>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at the explanation of type erasure and type checks for generic types in the language reference: [Type erasure and generic type checks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36253310/how-to-get-actual-type-arguments-of-a-reified-generic-parameter-in-kotlin).

Basically, you cannot do that sort of check because the instances of `SettingsKeyContractWithType` do not hold any information about their actual type argument at runtime.

An option that you could try here is to add make `SettingsKeyContractWithType` explicitly store some representation of the type argument. A simple `KClass` does not seem to fit, because it cannot represent a concrete generic type (you cannot have a `KClass` for `List<String>`.

If that's really what you want, consider using the technique of super type tokens, as described here: [(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36253310/how-to-get-actual-type-arguments-of-a-reified-generic-parameter-in-kotlin).

You can add a `TypeReference<T>` property to `SettingsKeyContractWithType`, fill it within an inline factory function with a reified type parameter.