# Why are Kotlin reified functions better?

Tags: kotlin

[The official Kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45952201/5377) do a great job of explaining how Kotlin `reified` allows us to change something like:

```
myJsonString.toData(MyDataClass::class)
```

To:

```
myJsonString.toData<MyDataClass>()
```

But I don't think either do a good job of explaining the motivation. Is the reified function only preferable because it saves a few characters? Or are there other benefits to not having to pass the class in as a parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One more advantage of reified type parameters is that they provide full type information, including type arguments, when the type is known at compile time.

```
abstract class TypeReference<T> : Comparable<TypeReference<T>> {
    val type: Type = 
        (javaClass.genericSuperclass as ParameterizedType).actualTypeArguments[0]

    override fun compareTo(other: TypeReference<T>) = 0
}

inline fun <reified T: Any> printGenerics() {
    val type = object : TypeReference<T>() {}.type
    if (type is ParameterizedType)
        type.actualTypeArguments.forEach { println(it.typeName) }
}
```

```
printGenerics<HashMap<Int, List<String>>>()
```

> ```
> java.lang.Integer
> java.util.List<? extends java.lang.String>
> ```

See: [How to get actual type arguments of a reified generic parameter in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36253310/how-to-get-actual-type-arguments-of-a-reified-generic-parameter-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 4):

The other benefit is that the type parameter can be inferred. For example:

```
fun foo(myData: MyDataClass) { ... }

foo(myJsonString.toData()) // no need to specify MyDataClass at all
```

Answer (score 1):

The motivation is **type erasure** in the end. Generics on the JVM are cool but only help at compile time. With `reified`, you can make generic types available at runtime. This results in cleaner APIs as demonstrated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45952201/5377) and yole's answer, cleaner DSLs (they utilize reified a lot), and certainly also easier implementations that rely on type information which would be erased normally as shown by hotkey.

Comment: For me, "knowing the type at compile time within the method" isn't a motivation by itself. Things like typing less, better runtime performance, fewer classes in the class loader, these seem like motivations on their own. I probably just don't have enough experience for that to be intrinsically valuable, but AFAICT fewer type annotations (@yole's point) and understanding a type's hierarchy of generic params (@hotkey's point) both still fall under the "typing less" motivation. And once again, that's fine and valuable, I'm just wondering if there's anything else.